Where should we promote our site and what images should be used?
Update
I've submitted the accepted logo below to Math, IT Security, and CS Theory. Please go to those sites (use links to meta post below) to upvote so our ad will appear on those sites. If there are other sites we should consider, please submit them as an answer.
Also, don't feel like you can't submit a new logo if desired. If one gains more votes, I'll switch to that.
Old Info
Graduated SE sites each have a meta question where users can submit ads, which if upvoted at least 6 times will be displayed on the main site. This provides a good way for us to promote Crypto.SE on other SE sites.
Which sites should we target for ads?
What ad should we use (i.e., we don't have one AFAIK, so design one, post it here and see what other people like)?
Potential Sites to advertise on
Math (2013 meta post)
CS Theory (2013 meta post)
IT Security (2013 meta post)
When we submit an ad it is of the form  
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url 
So please post this information in your answers to make it easy to add on to the target sites.

I've never seen a community ad that promotes another SE site. Are you sure it should be used like that?

@CodesInChaos the Math.SE and CSTheory.SE posts have Academia.SE ads in the meta post and they both have enough votes to be shown as ads.

Communities promoting communities sounds interesting… have yet to see it too though. (I'm probably member of the wrong communities.)

@e-sushi for an example check out Math.SE. On the right hand side you will see a small banner for other sites (not necessarily SE sites, but they can be).

Finally found some examples via meta.programmers.SE… and this answer is the result.

Humbly proposing my design:


Best one I've seen so far :) In all seriousness, I like it. I made the post "featured" again in hopes to draw some attention. I'll wait a few days and see if we get anything else or any strong negatives.

I like it, especially from a cryptography history POV, but I think it might place too much emphasis on classical cryptography for my tastes... while we do admittedly sometimes entertain questions about classical cryptography, I think we really need to cultivate modern-day cryptography questions. If we're going to do a promotion, I'd prefer something that flat-out shows that we're mostly interested in modern-day stuff. There are a lot of "code" websites out there that I specifically avoid because I'm mostly interested in modern-day stuff, and I think we need to actively avoid that image.

+1, even if I do also echo Reid's concerns. Still, it's a really nice ad, and I do feel we should at least give it a try. We can always withdraw it later if it turns out to attract the wrong kind of crowd for our site.

Reid has a good point. This is a very good design, IMO, but it doesn't show or represent anything that the viewer would actually read about daily on the site. Someone on a Math or CS site that saw this may think more "codes" and less "modern crypto".

@e-sushi, fyi, someone is asking about your logo: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/1365/5882

Based on the comment by Reid, I've come up with a more "modern" alternative:

I hope this one is able to represent the "modern-day stuff" (and the days after) a bit better. You decide…
EDITS:

2013-08-03 02:36:00 +01:00
Updated the image, taking into account the comment by mikeazo.
2013-08-07 02:26:00 +01:00
Updated the image, taking into account the comment by B-Con.


I like this one too. My only complaint is I think RSA is too prominent. I'd make it smaller, add in AES and SHA1 in a similar fashion. Just my 2 cents. Great job though.

@mikeazo Took care of your complaint. :) Jokes aside, I added your SHA1 and AES, and I added KECCAK to the pack too to get some kind of "progress" (which hopefully makes sense to anyone besides me).

It's not bad, but to be honest, I like your other ad more (even if it is "old-fashioned").

@IlmariKaronen Personally, I prefer the other one too. On the other hand, my opinion doesn't really count here…

Perhaps a nitpick, but I would swap the ordering of the names. In order of most to least broken (by the amount of breakage of the name in the image), I'd suggest swapping AES and RSA since RSA has more problems than AES. Or for order of age, move RSA to the far left.

@B-Con Good point... I updated the image to take that into account.

Out of interest, what did you use to render this poster?

Actually, looking at the two designs again, I can see each of them working on different sites. This one would (IMO) totally not work on math.SE, but it might be good for, say, security.SE.

@IlmariKaronen: I've been thinking about this a fair bit lately, and I was thinking we could possibly do something akin to the cover of Foundations of Cryptography: Volume 1 for math.se and cstheory.se. I think both would especially appreciate the nod to one-way functions. Perhaps we could incorporate Feistel networks and the MD construction (or perhaps the sponge construction) somehow? Just throwing out "modern" ideas.
